# Positioning the arrow in custom drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a custom drop down list with two list items i.e predefined and custom. The problem is that the location of the arrow in the drop down list is fixed. when the first list item in the drop down is selected it looks good but when the second list item is selected it shows too much gap between the list item and arrow. I want the arrow location to be adjusted according the list item which is selected. Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            event.stopPropagation();
        }); 

        obj.opts.on('click',function(){
            var opt = $(this);
            var orgVal = $("#ddtext").text();
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            $("#ddtext").text(obj.val);
            opt.text(orgVal);
            $(this).css('wrapper-dropdown-7');

        });
    }
}
$(function() {

                var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

                $(document).click(function() {
                    // all dropdowns
                    //$('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
                });

            });

</script>
<style>
.wrapper-dropdown-5 {
    /* Size & position */
    position: relative;
    width: 144px;
    margin: 0 auto;


    /* Styles */
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5:after { /* Little arrow */
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    border-width: 9px 9px 0 7px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #067ab4 transparent;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown {
    /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: -38;
    right: 0;

    /* Styles */

    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

    /* Hiding */
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #067ab4;
    padding: 0px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
}
/* Hover state */
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li:hover a {
    color: #57a9d9;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5.active .dropdown {
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    max-height: 400px;
}
div#dd
{
color: #067ab4;
font: 30px tahoma;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 45px;
}
div#textA
{
display: inline-block;
font: 30px tahoma;
padding-left: 20px;
margin-top: 45px;
}
div#textB
{
display: inline-block;
font: 30px tahoma;
padding-left: 40px;
margin-top: 45px;
}
span#ddtext
{
border-bottom: 1px solid #067ab4;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>   <div id="textA">I want to select a</div>
         <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-5" tabindex="1"><span id="ddtext">Predefined</span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Custom</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div  id="textB">profile</div>
    </body>
   <html>
```

Comment: Hi Evan. Here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/R5aHa/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to make some changes to your CSS, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls6pb/1/

Here are my edits to you CSS:

```
.wrapper-dropdown-5 {
    /* Size & position */
    position: relative;
    /*width: 144px;*/
    margin: 0 auto;


    /* Styles */
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
span#ddtext:after{
    content:" ▾"
}
/* Little arrow .wrapper-dropdown-5:after { 
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    border-width: 9px 9px 0 7px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #067ab4 transparent;
}*/
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown {
    /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: -38;
    right: 0;

    /* Styles */

    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

    /* Hiding */
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #067ab4;
    padding: 0px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
}
/* Hover state */
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li:hover a {
    color: #57a9d9;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5.active .dropdown {
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    max-height: 400px;
}
div#dd
{
color: #067ab4;
font: 30px tahoma;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 45px;
}
div#textA
{
display: inline-block;
font: 30px tahoma;
padding-left: 20px;
margin-top: 45px;
}
div#textB
{
display: inline-block;
font: 30px tahoma;
/*padding-left: 40px;*/
margin-top: 45px;
}
span#ddtext
{
border-bottom: 1px solid #067ab4;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help, if it's the right answer for you, feel free to click on the little checkmark beside my answer and give it an upvote :)

Comment: Hi ShemSeger. Its working in jsfiddle but when I run it on chrome through my notepad++ it is showing some undefined symbol in place of arrow.

Comment: content:" ▾" This symbol is not working in notepad++.

Comment: Now its working but the text in the list item "predefined" in the drop down list is cutting.

Comment: My guess is that it's cutting to be the same width as "custom," am I right? Sounds like a device specific problem, I would recommend opening another question and being very specific about what device/browser you're having the issue in, I can't seem to reproduce the problem on my computer.

Comment: Its working fine now. I just added width: 144px; in my css.

.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown {
    /* Size & position */
 width: 144px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: -38;
    right: 0;

    /* Styles */

    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

    /* Hiding */
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}